# scala : method not getting called without adding private modifier

Tags: scala, class, oop, jvm

i am new to scala and cant seem to notice any issue here. As mentioned in code comments, `if(enableXMLMessageLog(method))`  is evaluating to false without executing the method enableXMLMessageLog . Once i add private to this method, it starts to work as expected and returns true on evaluation.

The methods are member of an abstract class.

[image]

Any idea what is happening here and why is it only getting called after adding private ?

Comment: This does not make any sense. Please check out [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and try to edit your question to include a reproducible example. 
Also, do not post pictures of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i got it . the method was being called from a unit test class and only the logBookingMessage method was set to `when(messageLogger.logBookingMessage(any[LoggingMethod])).thenCallRealMethod()` hence it was not able to call the method `enableXMLMessageLog` as it was being mocked and thus returning false.

On adding private to the method, mocking framework does not mock and call the actual implementation of the method hence returning true.